# dockerfile.template vs dockerfile

Tags: docker, aws-lambda

At my org, I frequently see Dockerfile.template used instead of Dockerfile. I'm curious why the former might be used over the latter? (For context, the deployment is typically AWS Lambda using the [awslambdaric](https://pypi.org/project/awslambdaric/) package to enable broader selection of base images for lambda use case.)

At any rate, does the template approach enable more customizability, does it abstract xyz, or is the difference immaterial?

Comment: The Dockerfile can be named whatever. It sounds like there's a certain standard being used in your org

Comment: Hmm, so suppose a build system knows to look in a folder `./configuration` for a dockerfile. This file could be called anything, docker would be indifferent and the build system wouldn't care either so long as the file was located in the dir.

Comment: What tool processes the `Dockerfile.template`, or is it just passed in with a `docker build -f` option?  How old is your setup?  (A very very long time ago Docker didn't support build-time `ARG`, for example.)

Comment: @DavidMaze- not certain, an internal build system that's been evolving over last three decades (Docker support is a fairly recent addition compared earlier iterations in the 90s.)